# How to create a QnA database design

Tags: database-design

i have a project where we have a CMS for the admin to create questions so that users can answer on. Its like some sort of survey, the user signs in and fill in the answer of the questions that the admin has added in the CMS. Now that's not the tricky part, the tricky part is that the admin will create a series of surveys where he would should choose who can see this surveys. So in the CMS he chooses the question and the answer that should be related to a user for example: A survey can only be seend for Males between the age of 15 to 21. So in the CMS the steps are the following; create the questions, create the survey, link the survey to the question and choose an answer (Age: 15 to 21).
How can i create the database of this kind of flow? What i came up with is the following:
**Question Types**

- id
- type

**Questions**

- id
- question
- question_type_id

**Question User**

- question_id
- user_id
- value

**Survey Question** (the tricky part that i can't figure out)

- question_id
- survey_id
- value ?? (not sure if this should be a json field or do another thing)

Hope u guys can give me another idea about the database design.

Comment: Designing the database requires understanding of the business requirements, which is not a programming question. Remember, SO is a software development related Q/A site! Please update your question to be a single, specific, software-development related question that does not require understanding of your entire questionnaire module! What is the problem you are facing with Survey Questions table?

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you state the domain in a semi structured language. If I understand it correctly:

```
The system has two types of users, "administrators" and "answerers".
Answerers can belong to zero or more groups.
The system has many surveys.
A survey is applicable to exactly one group.
A survey has many questions.
An answerer can answer each question once.
```

If this is correct, it's much easier to derive the entities and relationships.

```
*User*
User_id (pk)
User_type (enum)

*Group*
Group_id (pk)
Description

*User_group*
User_id (pk, fk)
Group_id (pk, fk)

*Survey*
Survey_id (pk)
Group_id (fk)
....

*Question*
Question_id (pk)
Survey_id (fk)
Question_text 
....

*Answer*
Question_id (pk, fk)
User_id (pk, fk)
Answer_text
....
```